# Spring Boot 3.2 - Multicluster MongoDB Connection with NodePort

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-data-mongodb, kubernetes-nodeport

I have a Spring Boot 3.2 (RC2) based application that connects to MongoDB.
My MongoDB is a ReplicaSet deployed on two Kubernetes clusters:

- three nodes on cluster A (and one arbiter)
- three nodes on cluster B
  The nodes (therefore pods) are exposed via NodePort, so all the synchronization of the ReplicaSet takes place via NodePort.

My *rs.status()* gives a result similar to the following:

```
{
  set: 'rsTest',
  date: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:31.374Z"),
  myState: 1,
  term: Long("2"),
  syncSourceHost: '',
  syncSourceId: -1,
  heartbeatIntervalMillis: Long("2000"),
  majorityVoteCount: 4,
  writeMajorityCount: 4,
  votingMembersCount: 7,
  writableVotingMembersCount: 6,
  optimes: {
    lastCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
    lastCommittedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.165Z"),
    readConcernMajorityOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
    appliedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208750, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
    durableOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208750, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
    lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
    lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z")
  },
  lastStableRecoveryTimestamp: Timestamp({ t: 1700208716, i: 7 }),
  electionCandidateMetrics: {
    lastElectionReason: 'electionTimeout',
    lastElectionDate: ISODate("2023-11-10T11:37:02.387Z"),
    electionTerm: Long("2"),
    lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") },
    lastSeenOpTimeAtElection: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1699616220, i: 9 }), t: Long("1") },
    numVotesNeeded: 1,
    priorityAtElection: 5,
    electionTimeoutMillis: Long("10000"),
    newTermStartDate: ISODate("2023-11-10T11:37:02.392Z"),
    wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate: ISODate("2023-11-10T11:37:02.399Z")
  },
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1>:30100',
      health: 1,
      state: 1,
      stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
      uptime: 592530,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208750, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1699616222, i: 1 }),
      electionDate: ISODate("2023-11-10T11:37:02.000Z"),
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2,
      self: true,
      lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      name: '<ARBITER-SVC>:27017',
      health: 1,
      state: 7,
      stateStr: 'ARBITER',
      uptime: 592517,
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.975Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.977Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '',
      syncSourceId: -1,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 592478,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.080Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:31.179Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1>:30100',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-3>:30102',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 592447,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 6 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.553Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.190Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.775Z"),
      pingMs: Long("0"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101',
      syncSourceId: 2,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 4,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-1>:30100',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 25736,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.165Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.165Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.370Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:28.906Z"),
      pingMs: Long("596"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101',
      syncSourceId: 2,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 5,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-2>:30101',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 21862,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208749, i: 2 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.165Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.165Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:30.790Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.443Z"),
      pingMs: Long("175"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101',
      syncSourceId: 2,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    },
    {
      _id: 6,
      name: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-2>:30102',
      health: 1,
      state: 2,
      stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
      uptime: 41858,
      optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208742, i: 1 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDurable: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1700208741, i: 5 }), t: Long("2") },
      optimeDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:22.000Z"),
      optimeDurableDate: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:21.000Z"),
      lastAppliedWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:22.457Z"),
      lastDurableWallTime: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:21.511Z"),
      lastHeartbeat: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:29.040Z"),
      lastHeartbeatRecv: ISODate("2023-11-17T08:12:28.382Z"),
      pingMs: Long("1115"),
      lastHeartbeatMessage: '',
      syncSourceHost: '<WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1>:30100',
      syncSourceId: 0,
      infoMessage: '',
      configVersion: 17,
      configTerm: 2
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1700208750, i: 6 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("3pWba14pRUH9FpER+6qWF6I=", 0),
      keyId: Long("7299796089241075715")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1700208750, i: 6 })
}
```

So the members of the ReplicaSet were randomly assigned to worker nodes of my Kubernetes clusters. So far so good.

In the Spring Boot application the value of *spring.data.mongodb.uri* is as follows:

```
mongodb://my_user:my_pwd@
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1>:30100,
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101,
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-3>:30102,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1>:30100,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2>:30101,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-3>:30102,
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-1>:30100,
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-2>:30101,
<MASTER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-3>:30102,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-1>:30100,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-2>:30101,
<INFRA-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-3>:30102
/my_db?replicaSet=rsTest&authSource=my_db
```

instead of connecting to the IPs of the nodes assigned to the ReplicaSet, I use the NodePorts to use the IPs of my Master and Infra nodes (more stable) of my Kubernetes clusters.

The result is that sometimes the application starts correctly and works although I rightly see logs like this:

> <MASTER-NODE-..> is no longer a member of the replica set. Removing from client
> view of cluster

but often it doesn't start due to the MongoHealthIndicator timeout:

> o.s.b.a.health.HealthEndpointSupport     : Health contributor
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.data.mongo.MongoHealthIndicator
> (mongo) took 30103ms to respond

caused by:

> Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches
> ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of
> cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET,
> servers=[{address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-3:30102,
> type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=20.0 ms, state=CONNECTED},
> {address=ARBITER-SVC:27017, state=CONNECTED},
> {address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-2:30101, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY,
> roundTripTime=20.7 ms, state=CONNECTED},
> {address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-A-IP-1:30100, type=UNKNOWN,
> state=CONNECTING}, {address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-3:30102,
> type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, roundTripTime=715.3 ms, state=CONNECTED},
> {address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-2:30101, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY,
> roundTripTime=131.8 ms, state=CONNECTED},
> {address=WORKER-NODE-CLUSTER-B-IP-1:30100, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY,
> roundTripTime=793.6 ms, state=CONNECTED}]

apparently it can't connect to the primary.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Why sometimes the application starts without problems but instead I often get these errors and the application doesn't start?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: First things first: Your MongoDB cluster setup does not make sense. If DC1 fails, the whole cluster goes down, so why have a a second DC in the first place. Why not put a the arbiter into a third datacenter? That being said: Are the IP-Adresses of each of the clusters known to each other? Can you ping ALL addresses in DC1 from DC2 and vice versa?

Comment: Why should the entire cluster fail in case of DC1 down? A DC2 node would become primary. Having said that: yes all the IPs are known. In any case, rolling back to Spring Boot M2 solved the boot problems. It's probably a Spring Boot 3.2 RC2 bug.

Comment: Njet. The quorum is calculated from the initial voting nodes. If DC1 goes down, the remaining voting nodes (3) cannot create a quorum (4). The cluster even tells you that:  `majorityVoteCount: 4, writeMajorityCount: 4, votingMembersCount: 7,`